# Casting AsyncTask in Android

Tags: java, android, generics, casting, android-asynctask

I have two `AsyncTasks` in my activity that use different argument types each:

```
private class TaskA extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Boolean> { ... }
private class TaskB extends AsyncTask<byte[], byte[], Boolean>
```

Both sub classes implement a method `public boolean SendDataToNetwork(final byte[] cmd)` which can be called from the gui thread.

I'd like to have a reference in my activty that points to either `TaskA` or `TaskB` depending on which arguments get passed to my activity with an intent.

What I did try so far is:

```
private AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> myTask = null;
```

and

```
 switch(mode) {
    case 1: 
        myTask = new TaskA();
        break;
    case 0:
        myTask = new TaskB();
        break;
    }
```

However, when I try to execute `myTask` later in the code with

```
myTask.execute();
```

this leads to a compile error:
`Type safety: A generic array of capture#7-of ? is created for a varargs parameter`

How can I properly cast `myTask` to `TaskA` or `TaskB` according to the switch-case statement?

**Update:**

Initializing `myTask` with:

```
private AsyncTask myTask = null;
```

yields to one warning:

```
myTask= new TaskA();
myTask.execute();

The method execute(Object...) belongs to the raw type AsyncTask. References to generic type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> should be parameterized
```

If I try to use the method `SendDataToNetwork` I get an error now:

```
The method SendDataToNetwork(byte[]) is undefined for the type AsyncTask
```

It looks like the object `myTask` is never really casted to the type `TaskA` or `TaskB`?

Comment: You need to show us more code. The warning indicates that you are using a method with a varargs parameter. You should show that.

Comment: Try not use generic syntax define myTask, i.e. private AsyncTask myTask = null;

Comment: Please see the updated code above.

Comment: Your problem is that you think that your classes have a common ancestor, which they do not. `AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Boolean>` and `AsyncTask<byte[], byte[], Boolean>` are different classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are counting on being able to call SendDataToNetwork on both task types, perhaps your AsyncTask subclasses should implement an Interface that declares it.

Comment: The issue is that the parent class `AsyncTask` does not have the method `SendDataToNetwork` and I am declaring `myTask` as `AsyncTask`

Comment: You could extend AsyncTask and implement an interface at the same time.